# Ceiling truss uplift?

Tags: ceiling, crack, truss

Truss uplift or standard drywall crack? There is a hairline crack that runs horizontally to this one for roughly 2 inches.[image: truss crack]

Comment: We really need some context to orientate where that is in your home.

Comment: Top floor bedroom. The entire room was replastered prior to us moving in in December and we just had a week where the weather fell below 0 several times.

Comment: I imagine that is 0 F, plus just being redone, the frost is not playing nice.  It would not be uncommon to hear bangs as the wood expands/shrinks(usually late at night as you are half asleep).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your info on the location and situation, that is most likely expansion and contraction of dissimilar materials.